# SuperCollider patterns library: how to get a reference to the synths' nodeIDs?

Tags: supercollider

Patterns library question:
How can I get a reference to the Synth that is created by a Pbind?
For instance,

`Pbind(
\type, myCustomSynthDef,
\midinote, Pseq([60, 62, 64], inf),
\dur, 0.5
).play`

gets me a repeating do-re-mi sequence. If I'd like to change some modulation parameter on the synth that plays 're', how can I get that synth's nodeID into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

To control the "re" synth, you would normally put some extra parameters into the Pbind and then simply use them in the synth, e.g. add

`\craziness, Pseq([0, 100, 0], inf)`

to your Pdef, and add something in your SynthDef to use it.

If you really really want to know the nodeID (bleh, not pleasant) then you don't use `Pattern.play`. I guess you could iterate the pattern manually (e.g. using `.next`) and manually call `.play` on each `Event` in that iteration. When you call the `Event`'s `.play` it returns an Event that has the node ID inside, stored in the `id` key.